# How to read data from csv file in jmeter whose location is not fixed and might change in the future

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV File whose location is going to change later. Using Jmeter how can I still read the file even if the location change?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the location of the CSV file as a JMeter property and pass it through the command line or through `user.properties` file

1. Set the file name with a property in the CSV Data Set Config element

```
${__P(full-path-to-file,/Users/hansi/Documents/test-data/test-data-users.csv)}
```

[image]

**Note**: A default value `/Users/hansi/Documents/test-data/test-data-users.csv` is set in the above screenshot.

---

2.Define the value

2.1 In `user.properties` file

```
full-path-to-file=/Users/hansi/Documents/test-data/test-data-users.csv
```

or

2.2 Set the property when JMeter test is executed from commandline

./jmeter.sh -n -t test-plan.jmx -Jfull-path-to="/Users/hansi/Documents/test-data/test-data-users.csv"

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV file is going to change location then you could store the test plan which is using the file alongside it. This would maintain the context of the test plan if the CSV itself is going to be moving by storing them together. In JMeter relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan (based on the official [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)), allowing you to specify only the name of the file in the CSV Data Set Config Filename property.